# How can I access HttpContext Header values in Static class

Tags: static, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcontext

I am programming an ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API.

I have a `CurrentUser` class like this. I want to access the header info anywhere in the project by using `CurrentUser.Id`. How can I do that? (or where can I initialize `httpContext` variable?)

```
public class CurrentUser
{   
    private static HttpContext _context;        
    private static UserDto _myUserObj;

    public static void Initialize(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        _context = context.HttpContext;
        _myUserObj = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User"] as UserDto;
    }

    public static int Id()
    {
        return _myUserObj.Id
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592326/access-to-httpcontext-via-static-class-works-correctly-with-different-requests . You shouldn't do it

Comment: I have already read this article before open my subject.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solutions. But I think its not best practice solutions. (There must be another and better way..)

**MySolutions is that:**
I am building a custom Attribute and i am adding it every API Controller like this:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class UserController : ControllerBase{
    //blablabla
}
```

After this : I am setting my **CurrentUser.Initilaze()** method in this Attribute like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyCustomAttribute: Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

        //fortest
        var userObj = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User"];//working
        var userObj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserDto>(userObj, new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });//working

        CurrentUser.Initialize(context);//working
        var testResult = CurrentUser.Test();//working
        
    }
}
```

So I can use CurrentUser static class everywhere in N-Layerd project and I am accessing UserId or another variables..

But i am saying again, I think its not best solution. Because  **I have to add [MyCustomAttribute] to all Controllers**.  There must be a better solition.